# Server.TransferRequest does not get correct page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

we are using HttpModule for switching aspx pages..

But if large number of client try to **hit same time** then people get wrong page on screen... I am not sure if something wrong in my code due to `Server.TransferRequest`.

Can any one give any suggestion?

```
public class SwitchMasterModule : IHttpModule, IRequiresSessionState
    { 

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += Context_BeginRequest;
        }

        void Context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var AppId = SiteSettings.ApplicationId().ToString();
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.Equals("/default.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Server.TransferRequest(string.Format("~/Templates/{0}/default.aspx", AppId), true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any other HttpModules loaded that could interfere with this behavior?

Comment: What page do they get instead?  A page whose template comes from the wrong AppID?

Comment: Is `SiteSettings` your class?

Comment: No other HttpModules @jason

Comment: @AnnL. Yes it get wrong appid page. but it work fine I load sites one by one it happens you can say 1 out of 50 times

Comment: @SOFUser It might be that `SiteSettings.ApplicationId()` returns incorrect value. What is inside `SiteSettings.ApplicationId()`?

Comment: @Win can you type this as answer so i can mark this as answer

Answer (score 0):

*Moved from comment to answer.*

It might be that `SiteSettings.ApplicationId()` returns incorrect value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the origin of the `SiteSettings` class is, but if it's not absolutely thread-safe, you could easily wind up with one user accessing the `ApplicationId` value appropriate for another user.